# How to check the pointcloud data rate from the turtlebot laptop to the workstation?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am successfully getting the pointclouds from the turtlebot and am able to view the cloud in my workstation. I would like to know the rate at which the original published data reaches the workstation so as to process the cloud in the similar or lesser rate.
How to check the rate?

Any help here is appreciated.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

When i do the

```
rostopic hz /camera/rgb/points
```

I get the following response

```
average rate: 0.177
    min: 5.369s max: 7.301s std dev: 0.35833s window: 26
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
average rate: 0.177
    min: 5.369s max: 7.301s std dev: 0.35166s window: 27
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
no new messages
average rate: 0.177
    min: 5.369s max: 7.301s std dev: 0.34511s window: 28
no new messages
```

How do i interpret this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28715/how-to-check-the-pointcloud-data-rate-from-the-turtlebot-laptop-to-the-workstation?/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-02-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-02-28**:
You are getting messages at 0.177 Hz, that is about 1 message every 6s.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-02-28**:
1 message here is the entire cloud right? 640x480 points in a single msg?

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2012-02-28**:
Yes, each message is an entire cloud. Resolution depends on your settings. One cloud at full resolution has almost 10 MByte of data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do that using

```
rostopic hz [your_point_cloud_topic]
```

Note that you shouldn't run your other workstation processes requesting the pointcloud at the same time, as this will require additional bandwidth.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-02-28**:
Thanks Stefan. May i know how to interpret the above msgs?